# Select combo box option with VBA in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a form with a combo box. Selecting certain options in the combo box will trigger different actions in the form.

I'd like to have the first dropdown option automatically selected when I open the form or go to the next record. Using the VBA command `ComboBox.Value = "Option1"` only inputs a string into the combo box; it's not the same as clicking an option manually and does not trigger the other actions.

How do I select an option in a combo box dropdown in a way that Access recognizes it the same as clicking it?

Comment: Which combobox event are you using to trigger actions? Is your combobox data source a Table/Query or a List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting the combobox value as stated in the other answers, then calling the AfterUpdate event, where my actions are coded. The event triggers and uses the `ComboBox.Value` I set using VBA.

```
ComboBox.Value = "Option1"
Call ComboBox_AfterUpdate
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to update/change a comboxbox value with the use of a button , in the on click event

```
me.combobox.value = "option1"
```

Comment: I'm not looking to perform an action based on a combo box value - I have that working. I'm looking to use VBA to select the option, so for example, if I click a button on the form, the button's On Click event populates the combo box.

Comment: edited the solution, just change the value of the combo box in the on click event

Comment: Still doesn't trigger the actions associated with the combo box. I tried putting the code in the other events too, but none of them work.

Comment: In the Form_Load event:

Comment: Form_Load will only run it when I open the form. I need it to run whenever I change the combo box.

Comment: could you post what you have actually written for the on click event?Also, what is the row source for your combo box? Query or list?  I cant see the reason why it does not work

Comment: This was enough to assign a value to the combo box as desired.

Answer (score 1):

In the code below, change Combo7 to the name of your ComboBox. Change Filed1 to the Fieldname of your table. Change option1 to your option string:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
   If IsNull(Me.recordSet.field1) Then
       Me.recordSet.Edit
       Me.recordSet.Field1 = "option1"
       Me.recordSet.Update
   End If
   Call Combo7_Change
End Sub
```

In the code below, change Text9.Value to the code you want executed when the form opens or the record is changed:

```
Private Sub Combo7_Change()
    Select Case Combo7.Value
    Case "option1"
       Text9.Value = 1
    Case "option2"
       Text9.Value = 2
    Case "option3"
       Text9.Value = 3        
    End Select    
End Sub
```

Let me know if you have anu questions.

Comment: How is `Me.recordSet.Field1 = "option1"` different from `ComboBox.Value = "Option1"`? The `Call` function is new to me, I'll give that a try.

Comment: ConboBox.Value will only set the form field to Option1. The technique I have shown updates the corresponding ComboBox field in the Recordset. Try it. I tested it and it works.

Comment: I did, if I put the name of the bound column as Field1, "option1" doesn't show up. If I replace the If statement with `ComboBox.Value = "option1"`, "option1" shows up for an instant then is replaced by the first row in the table the combo box writes to. If I type it in the combo box manually, it stays. Does it have something to do with how the combo box is bound?

Comment: Is the table being updated, even when you do not enter a value? Field1 should be the name of the field that ComboBox is bound to. The way it should work is that when cycling through the recordset if you do not enter a value in the ComboBox, it should default to Option1.  Can you post the new On Current and On Change code?